# Creating a textarea when user clicks button

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering what the best way to approach this next feature is. 
Right now, when user selects "no" an alert appears. However, I would like for a text area box to appear, instead. Any help or leads on how to tackle this?  My first thought is that my if statement will have to change, correct?  Any leads are appreciated.   I provided a snippet for you to view of what I have so far.

```js
let button = document.querySelector("input.button");

button.addEventListener("click", question1);

function question1() {
  var selection = document.querySelector("input[name='groupOfDefaultRadios']:checked");

  if (selection.value == 'yes') {
    alert("Thank you for your kindness");
  } else {
    alert("We are sorry! Please write to us telling us what was wrong");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="clienthelp-card">
  <form id="myForm">
    <h4> Was this helpful?</h4>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultGroupExample1" name="groupOfDefaultRadios" value="yes">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultGroupExample1">Yes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultGroupExample2" name="groupOfDefaultRadios" value="no">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultGroupExample2">No</label>
    </div>
    <input class="button" type="button" name="groupOfDefaultRadios" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `const answer = prompt('Type some text')` since you're already using `alert`. The [`prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) function pops up a blocking textbox.

Comment: Please clarify "text area box" and what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built in alert function cannot be used to get user input.

You can add a hidden div which replaces the alert and where you can also add HTML elements.

Please find slightly modified version of your code to get the idea below:

```html
     <div class="clienthelp-card">
                                    <form id="myForm">
                                        <h4> Was this helpful?</h4>
                                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                            <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultGroupExample1" name="groupOfDefaultRadios" value="yes">
                                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultGroupExample1">Yes</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                            <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultGroupExample2" name="groupOfDefaultRadios" value="no">
                                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultGroupExample2">No</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <input class="button" type="button" name="groupOfDefaultRadios" value="Submit">
                                    </form>
                                </div>
<div id="result" style="display:none"></div>


<script>
    let button = document.querySelector("input.button");

button.addEventListener("click", question1);


function question1() {
  var selection = document.querySelector("input[name='groupOfDefaultRadios']:checked");
  var result = document.getElementById("result");
   if (selection.value == 'yes') {
    result.innerHTML = "Thank you for your kindness";
    result.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    var output = "";
    output += "We are sorry! Please write to us telling us what was wrong:<br />";
    output += "<textarea style='width: 100px; height 100px;'></textarea><br />";
    output += "<button>Submit</button>";
    result.innerHTML = output;
    result.style.display = "block";
    
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: clicking that "tidy" is nice on a snippet...for formatting

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few ways you can give a user something to enter text into and then handle it as you see fit.

The first way is to insert a `textarea` element and add a callback so that when the user selects OK, you can do what you want with the text.

The second way is to use `prompt` as called called out in other comments

```js
function okButtonCallback(evt) {
  const textArea = document.getElementById('textarea1');
  alert(`Text Area Text: ${textArea.value}`);
}

const btnTextArea = document.getElementById('textarea');
const btnPrompt = document.getElementById('prompt');

// Use a Text Area to get text and
// add a callback to handle the text
// when the user selects ok
btnTextArea.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const container = document.getElementById('myContainer');
  const textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
  textArea.id = 'textarea1';
  const okButton = document.createElement('button');
  okButton.innerText = 'OK';
  okButton.onclick = okButtonCallback;
  container.appendChild(textArea);
  container.appendChild(okButton);
});

// Use a prompt to get the text
btnPrompt.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const enteredText = prompt('Some sort of message');
  alert(`Prompt Text: ${enteredText}`);
});
```

```html
<button id="textarea">Show Text Area</button>
<button id="prompt">Show Prompt</button>

<div id="myContainer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a `<textarea id="whatever_you_want" hidden>` and you add in the `else` `document.getElementById("whatever_you_want").removeAttribute("hidden")`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can create a:

```
<input type="hidden" name="message" id="myAwesomeHiddenMessageField">
```

in your form and replacing your second alert by a prompt displaying the question like this :

```
let promptMessage = prompt("We are sorry! Please write to us telling us what was wrong");
```

And on submit or whatever :

```
document.querySelector('#myAwesomeHiddenMessageField').val(promptMessage);
```

Or you could use document.createElement to append a textearea to your form when "no" is selected. But I'm to lazy to help you more with this. And if you wan't to do this you gonna have to hide the generated textarea if the user choose "yes" in the end. Not sure if it's the best UX choose to make.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle a hidden text field, based on the selection of the radio button.

In the example below, a class is added to the text field to hide it. When the choice is changed to "yes", the class is added; if it is changed to "no", the class is added back.

```js
let submitButton = document.querySelector('input.button');
let radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
let hiddenTextArea = document.querySelector('.custom-textarea textarea');

// Add listeners
Array.from(radioButtons).forEach(radio => {
  radio.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    let hiddenWrapper = hiddenTextArea.parentElement;
    hiddenWrapper.classList.toggle('hidden-field', e.target.value !== 'no');
  });
});

submitButton.addEventListener('click', question1);

function question1() {
  var selection = document.querySelector("input[name='groupOfDefaultRadios']:checked");

  if (selection.value == 'yes') {
    alert("Thank you for your kindness");
  } else {
    alert("We are sorry! Please write to us telling us what was wrong");
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden-field {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="clienthelp-card">
  <form id="myForm">
    <h4> Was this helpful?</h4>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultGroupExample1" name="groupOfDefaultRadios" value="yes">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultGroupExample1">Yes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultGroupExample2" name="groupOfDefaultRadios" value="no">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultGroupExample2">No</label>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Here -->
    <div class="custom-control custom-textarea hidden-field">
      <textarea name="feedback"></textarea>
    </div>
    
    <input class="button" type="button" name="groupOfDefaultRadios" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to createElement when the user mark the "NO". I put notes inside this general demo:

```js
let radioI = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='groupOfDefaultRadios']"); // get radio in order to attach eventListener:
radioI.forEach((item) => { item.addEventListener("change", question1)}); // add change event that will trigger this function:
function question1() {
  var selection = document.querySelector('input[name="groupOfDefaultRadios"]:checked'); // this is your lines
   if (selection.value == 'yes') {
    alert('Thank you for your kindness');
// and/or submit the form progrematically using submit() etc... and/or redirect the user etc..
  } else {
    // create textarea element and display the submit button:
    var textA = document.createElement('textarea');
    textA.setAttribute('name', 'notHelpNote');
    textA.setAttribute('required', 'true');
    textA.placeholder = 'We are sorry! Please write to us telling us what was wrong';
    document.querySelector('#myForm').appendChild(textA);
    document.querySelector('#myForm input[type="submit"]').style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="clienthelp-card">
  <form id="myForm">
    <h4> Was this helpful?</h4>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultGroupExample1" name="groupOfDefaultRadios" value="yes">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultGroupExample1">Yes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultGroupExample2" name="groupOfDefaultRadios" value="no">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultGroupExample2">No</label>
    </div>
    <input class="button" type="submit" name="groupOfDefaultRadios" value="Submit" style="display: none;">
  </form>
</div>
```